# Toggle changed button class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a toggle button where will change button class from class="fa fa-toggle-off" to  class="fa fa-toggle-on" when clicked.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn" name="btn"><i id="change" class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i></button>
```

I create the javascript below, however it changed the button style="display:none" instead change its class.

```
       $(function() {
          $('#btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var display = true,
                image   = 'details_close.png';

            if ($('.td1:visible').length == $('.td1').length) { 
              display = false;
              image   = 'details_open.png';
            }

            $('.td1').toggle(display);

            $("#change").toggle(function() 
            {
                    $('#change').removeClass("fa-toggle-off").addClass("fa-toggle-on");
            }, function() {
                    $('#change').removeClass("fa-toggle-on").addClass("fa-toggle-off");
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any other events firing at the same time?

Comment: Isn’t jQuery’s `.toggle()` actually toggling the visibility (via CSS’ `display` attribute) of elements and thus the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Actually the button is used to toggle the table child row. And i want make the toggle button icon changed when clicked

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: In the code given you set up a listener each time a button is clicked; this is obviously wrong. What you actually should use is http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, I used `toggleClass` (http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function to toggle the class when you click your button, it'll disabled this class `fa-toggle-off` and activate this class `fa-toggle-on` on click 
 (https://api.jquery.com/click/) and vice versa.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function() {
     $("#change").toggleClass("fa-toggle-off fa-toggle-on");
  });
});
```

```css
.fa-toggle-off {
  background-color: #F00;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
  background-color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn" name="btn">
  Button <i id="change" class="fa fa-toggle-off">AAA</i>
</button>
```

Beware, in your code you're checking if `#change` is clicked, the button got `#btn` ID attribute.
Wish I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.toggleClass** to add or remove class alternatively

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#change").toggleClass("fa-toggle-on");
  });
});
```

```css
.fa-toggle-off {
  color: red;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
  color: blue;
}

.btn-default {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn" name="btn"><i id="change" class="fa fa-toggle-off">Hello my button</i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if on/off class exist and then can remove existing class & add new class as below code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var display = true,
            image   = 'details_close.png';

        if ($('.td1:visible').length == $('.td1').length) { 
          display = false;
          image   = 'details_open.png';
        }

        $('.td1').toggle(display);

        if ($("#change").hasClass("fa-toggle-off")) 
        {
            $('#change').removeClass("fa-toggle-off").addClass("fa-toggle-on");
        } else {
            $('#change').removeClass("fa-toggle-on").addClass("fa-toggle-off");
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps you.